# What is the predual space of $H_0^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I am trying to understand the predual space $X$ of $H_0^1(\Omega)$. My idea was to identify the predual space by the canonical embedding $i:X\to (H_0^1(\Omega))^{*}$. I know that a Hilbert space is isomorphic to its bidual space. I would like to say that $X$ is isomorphic to the dual space of $H_0^1(\Omega)$. But I think apriori this is not possible since I don't know if $X$ is reflexive. Am I mistaking, is it also possible to go backwards, so may I say that if $X''$ is a Hilbert space also $H$ is a Hilbert space ?
My second thought was to use the theorem of Riesz-Frechet to identify $X$ with $H_0^1(\Omega)$. Unluckily I would also need that $X$ is a Hilbert space. I think I'm overlooking something.

Can anyone please help me gain a better understanding of what is going on here?

Comment: If $X'$ is reflexive, then also $X$ is reflexive. Hence, any predual space must be a reflexive Banach space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For your conlusion you need that $X$ is a Banach space. Is there an argument to see this? Or am I mistaken and the conclusion is also more generally true without any assumption on $X$ ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that $X$ has to be complete for this argument. Otherwise, the completion of $X$ will be reflexive.

Comment: You're right, the completion will be reflexive. I forgot to ask about the existence. Is it really obvious that such a space exists ?